# Is a deleted comment received by the tagged user?

Tags: discussion, comments

Sometimes I delete a comment tagging a user, and for some reason or other, I delete the comment seconds or minutes after.

Does the recipient receive the notification and can see (at least part of) the comment in the "Recent Inbox messages" after it was deleted?

Answer (score 5):

It depends. I don't know the details, but from experience, I can tell you that you can sometimes get a notification and that it disappears when the comment is deleted. So yes, they will receive the notification, but it will go away when you delete the comment.